# Where is Win7's jump list system data stored?

Tags: windows-7, registry, taskbar, appdata, jump-list

As per [Jumplist Extender](http://jumplist.gsdn-media.com), I'm trying to prevent other apps from refreshing their jump lists (it's assumed that the user WANTS to do this, seeing as this is a JL editor.) One idea is to look for file or registry changes, where the data may be stored, and prevent the data from being written to.

The question is, where is the jump list data stored? It has to be *somewhere*! I know there's a folder location for pinned items, but I forgot what it is. It'd be great if I can get the "task" data, as well.

[Here's the original report](https://code.google.com/p/jumplist-extender/issues/detail?id=58).

Answer (score 9):

%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations

There's a file per application inside there.  As to how the filenames are mapped to application I don't know.

Comment: **JumpListsView** can be used to find out file names mapping: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/jump_lists_view.html

Comment: `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations\\` for `pinned` ones.

Answer (score 1):

Bad news, everyone. This is a .com file type. Its in a 'Structured Storage' file intended for .com programmers  only.

[Decrypt/Read/Modify “.automaticDestinations-ms” and/or ".customDestinations-ms"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429944/decrypt-read-modify-automaticdestinations-ms-and-or-customdestinations-ms)

Comment: This is a comment at best.